# If a Linux application calls a driver module and the driver module acquires a lock, what happens to the lock if the driver module crashes

Tags: c, linux-kernel, locking, linux-device-driver

"If a Linux application calls a driver module and the driver module acquires a lock, what happens to the lock if the driver module crashes unexpectedly (e.g., segmentation fault) or if the application process exits abnormally? Will the lock be released, for both spin locks and mutex locks?"

"If the lock is not released, is there any good solution?"

Comment: In the kernel neither spinlocks nor mutexes are released automatically. "If the lock is not released, is there any good solution?" - Just write a driver's code in a way that crash is impossible.

Comment: Any kernel module code running in a process context must release any locks it acquired in that context before returning to user-space. The module must use the appropriate functions to access the process's user-space memory. The module code must not have any spin-locks locked when if calls any kernel function that may sleep.

Comment: In the case where a process is in a kernel trap, which situations would cause it to be forcefully terminated by another process and result in an abnormal exit without releasing kernel resources?